# I get error (FunctionClauseError) no function clause matching in :raw_file_io_raw.open_layer/3 when I use ExAws

Tags: elixir

I am trying to us **ExAws** (https://github.com/ex-aws/ex_aws_s3) to upload to S3. I get this error:

```
** (FunctionClauseError) no function clause matching in :raw_file_io_raw.open_layer/3
```

It used to work before I upgraded to OTP 22 and Elixir 1.9 though.

I found this https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/issues/7771, however not sure if this is still applies.

Here is the code that do it:

```
cloud_s3.path
|> S3.Upload.stream_file
|> S3.upload(cloud_s3.s3_bucket, cloud_s3.s3_output)
|> ExAws.request
|> case do
  {:ok, result } ->
    Logger.warn "S3: Done for #{inspect(result)}"
  _ ->
    Logger.warn "S3: Err for #{inspect(cloud_s3)}, Not sure why!}"
end
```

Now I logged `cloud_s3.path |> S3.Upload.stream_file` out and here is the result:

```
%File.Stream{
  line_or_bytes: 5242880,
  modes: [:raw, :raw, {:read_ahead, 65536}, :binary, :binary],
  path: "/var/folders/3m/n6p202494w15b5xx0fc15y580000gn/T//plug-1562/multipart-1562739090-118134755902720-4",
  raw: true
}
```

`raw: true` this is the reason I get error. I am not sure how to fix it.

Per https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/File.html#stream!/3-raw-files this should work.

I think the solution is somehow I need to pass `raw: false` into `S3.Upload.stream_file`. There is no option for it though.

---

Here is the strange part. If I do this:

```
cloud_s3.path
|> File.stream!([], 5 * 1024 * 1024)
|> S3.upload(cloud_s3.s3_bucket, cloud_s3.s3_output)
|> ExAws.request
```

It works fine!!!

so [`S3.Upload.stream_file`](https://github.com/ex-aws/ex_aws_s3/blob/master/lib/ex_aws/s3/upload.ex#L52) function in the doc:

```
@spec stream_file(path :: binary) :: File.Stream.t
@spec stream_file(path :: binary, opts :: [chunk_size: pos_integer]) :: File.Stream.t
def stream_file(path, opts \\ []) do
  File.stream!(path, [], opts[:chunk_size] || 5 * 1024 * 1024)
end
```

Is pretty much the same though!!

I am very confused now.

```
      {:ex_aws, "~> 2.0"},
      {:ex_aws_s3, "~> 2.0"},
```

Comment: Which version of ex_aws_s3 do you have? It looks like this was [fixed in 2.0.1](https://github.com/ex-aws/ex_aws_s3/commit/3348d5cad2fcfcb3f3c70c0cc9657b7c1eaf32c0).

Comment: I have added to the question. I will try the `2.0.1` now